# Reloading subview (UICollectionview)

Tags: objective-c, ios, uicollectionview

In my ViewController I have four subviews, i.e UITableView, UICollectionView, View with UILabels, and View that displays preview image for that item.

By selecting a row in tableview, I am able to change preview image and all labels. However I can not refresh the UICollectionView data. I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8979585/reload-refresh-subviews-setneedsdisplay-doesnt-work) solution but it just removes and adds views and that changes the layout and preview image disappears.

All I want to do is refresh UICollectionView contents. Is there any simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried `[self.collectionView reloadData];` ?

Answer (score 1):

To refresh only a portion of the UICollectionView you could also call this:

```
[self.collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]]
```

where indexPath is the cell you want to reload.  You could include multiple index paths in the array as well. To reload the entire first section you could call this:

```
NSIndexSet *sections = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0];
[self.collectionView reloadSections:sections];
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have correctly hooked up your UICollectionView to a dataSource (UICollectionViewDataSource), you can call `[myCollectionView reloadData]` to make your collection view call your dataSource's methods (as below) to refresh itself:

```
– collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection:
– numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:
– collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:
– collectionView:viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:atIndexPath:
```

Comment: Hey Tommy. Yes everything was hooked up fine and i could load data in UICollectionView when VC loads for the first time. It only did not work when i tried to change item from within that ViewController. But it worked fine with the solution below. i.e [self.collectionView reloadData];. Thanks..